# Reading UUID from result set in Postgres JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm using UUID for my id column, I'm looking for a way to retrieve the data inside my Java application. I can't find a  method in ResultSet for getting a UUID. How would I go about getting the UUID?

Comment: I'm not well versed with Java but I think you could cast the UUID to text in the select statement and then use the standard getString method. To cast the id change your select statements as:  select id::text, ....

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is how it's done for anyone who searches

```
(java.util.UUID) result.getObject("id")
```

or

```
result.getObject("id", java.util.UUID.class)
```

Comment: Just a comment to say that this technique works also for sqlserver; maybe you can edit the title to a more generic one. Thank you!