# jdbc template getString on UUID not working

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have this method.

I am using jdbcTemplate query and then I am trying to return the list, however I am getting this error:

`Required type UUID provided String`

```java
 public List<Person> getPeople() {
        String sql = "SELECT * from people";
        List<Person> people = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (rs, idx) -> {
            return new Person(
                    result.getString("id"); <-------------- says can't fetch string because it's uuid type in db
            )
        })
    }
```

What do I need to use instead of `getString` in order for this to work?

Comment: How are you calling this `getPerson` method? Which line is the error occurring?

Comment: @TylerLiu just where it says `result.getString("id"),` The id is type UUID in my db.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate there's something wrong with the way you are calling the `getPerson` method.

Comment: @TylerLiu it no, I've edited my code. Check

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265904/reading-uuid-from-result-set-in-postgres-jdbc/56267754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `getObject` and casting it to UUID: `result.getObject("id", java.util.UUID.class)`